# get_post_types not working properly in admin

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, post-type

I'm trying to get all post types (custom & built_in) but it's only gives me only built_in ones in admin. I can get all of them in root (5 with builtins included) but in admin, i can only get 3.

I throught need a trigger an action or something but i couldn't find it.

```
    $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'name' ); 
    var_dump($post_types);
```

More info:
I'll use it in reduxframework's config page (in "setSection" function).

PS: I don't want to get post_types with sql query, because i need empty post_types too.

Edit: it is not about just admin.

For reduxframework developers; you can't use any function which uses the `init` action flag. For reference: https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework/issues/1181

Comment: `'name'` is not a valid value, it is `'names'` or '`objects'`. Can you try?

Comment: Stil same. I was getting object, with `'names'` get just names :) I thing it's must be an trigger or something to do this. Just getting core post types :/ Thanks for reply @cybmeta

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue. Can you verify that the custom post types you are trying to get are public? Are you using `get_post_types` in a action hook? If so, which one?

Comment: Nope I'm not usin it. I created a post type named "Portfolio".  Reduxframework can get it in fields. But in config things, it's not working. I used same arguments with redux. For information: args; `public` and `exclude_from_search`

Comment: You have to be sure to use `get_post_types` after `init` event. I can not tell you how to integrate this with Reduxframework (third party software is off-topic here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) is recommended to be used in `init` action hook. So, `get_post_types` should be used in an action after `init`. Hooking in `init` with a very high priority, 999 or greater, should also work in almost every situation but it is safer to use a later action hook.

Example:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', function(){
        $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'names' ); 
        var_dump($post_types);
});
```

In admin section you can use `admin_init`, which run after `init`:

```
add_action('admin_init', function(){
        $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'names' ); 
        var_dump($post_types);
});
```

Comment: It didn't solved my problem but thanks to you i get it why i can't to this.

For future reference: https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework/issues/1181